# EPPlus - Do I need to call Dispose on objects like ExcelRange?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm using the C# EPPlus library to create Excel documents.

```
ExcelWorksheet ws = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

ws.Cells["E3"].Value = "Foo";
ws.Cells["F3"].Value = "Bar";
ws.Cells["F3"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
```

The `ws.Cells[]` return type is ExcelRange which has a Dispose() method.
Do I need to call it each time I use `ws.Cells[]` ?

Something like

```
ExcelWorksheet ws = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
ExcelRange rng;

rng = ws.Cells["E3"];
rng.Value = "Foo";
rng.Dispose();

using (rng = ws.Cells["F3"])
{
    rng.Value = "Bar";
    rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
}
```

would be a heavy syntax !

Is it really necessary ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dispose, when is it called?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871888/dispose-when-is-it-called)

Comment: @mehow This was a library specific question. Examples found on EPPlus website doesn't mention that Dispose has to be called ; that's why I asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no.

Why?

I took a look in the source code from EPPlus and this is the content of the `Dispose` method of the `ExcelRangeBase`:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    //_worksheet = null;
}
```

I don't think this is going to help you in any way...

Comment: Anyone that winds up here, this is still correct as of this comment date.  Just looked it up to verify