# Will Dispose() cause a release of resources ahead of time in this case?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

I have this class:

```
class Foo : IDisposable
{
  SomeBigResource resource;

  void UsingResource()
  {
    using(Bar bar = new Bar(SomeBigResource)
      bar.doStuff();
  }

  void Dispose()
  {
    resource.Dispose();
  }
}

void Function()
{
  using (Foo foo = new Foo(new SomeBigResource))
    foo.UsingResource();
}
```

The Bar object has exactly the same `Dispose()` function.
Will my `SomeBigResource` be released or is the GC smart enough to release it later on when the second using is done?

Comment: a class the SomeBigResource belongs to has to dispose it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If both the `Dispose` methods in `Foo` and `Bar` calls `Dispose` on the `SomeBigResource` object, the method will be called twice. If the method is implemented correctly it will release the resources the first time and do nothing the second time.

What you have is a confusion of responsibility, where both objects take responsibility for calling `Dispose` on the `SomeBigResource` object. This is something that you want to avoid, as one object can't know if the other object still needs the resource, so you want to put the responsibility in one place only.

You should either make the `Foo` object responsible for the life cycle of the resource, or handle it outside of the objects completely. The latter makes more sense, as that's where you create the `SomeBigResource` instance:

```
using (SomeBigResource resource = new SomeBigResource()) {
  using (Foo foo = new Foo(resource)) {
    foo.UsingResource();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your resource will be disposed twice.

The GC is completely unaware of `IDisposable`s and the `using` statement.

Each `using` statement translates into a `try` / `finally` block with a `Dispose()` call in the finally block.
This is a normal method call which will always execute.

Therefore, the inner `using` statement in `UsingResource()` will dispose the resource, and then the outer `using` statement in `Function()` will dispose it again.

All `IDisposable` implementations *should* be idempotent (calling it a second time should do no harm).
Therefore, (assuming that `SomeBigResource` implements `IDisposable` correctly), your code should work fine.

Note, though, that with your class, an empty `using` block will throw a `NullReferenceException`, which is very wrong.
You should add a `null` check in your `Dispose` method.

Comment: So basically I should remove the using in UsingResource()?

Comment: Actually, you should remove the field and make it a private variable.

Comment: @the_drow, I would wrap the `using` around your instance of `SomeBigResource`, not the objects that are dependant upon that instance. `Foo` and `Bar` should not be responsible for cleaning up `SomeBigResource` if they did not create it.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the implementation of `Bar.Dispose()`. Assuming it has a similar implementation as `Foo`, then, yes, the release will occur early.

Take a look at the [Dispose pattern guidance](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/idisposable.aspx) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898828/c-finalize-dispose-pattern). There are more corner cases than you may think of immediately.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this line should read:

```
using(Bar bar = new Bar(resource))
```

If that's the case, then when `bar` is disposed, it *should* dispose of `resource`.

So, yes.  When `bar` is disposed in `UsingResource`, it will dispose `resource`, so that if you attempt to use it later, it *should* throw an `ObjectDisposedException`.  (Although in your simple example, that shouldn't happen.)