# Should IDisposable::Dispose() be virtual

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, idisposable, virtual-functions

Say a factory for SomeDisposable actually is creating/returning a sort of watch dog Wrapper

```
public class Wrapper : SomeDisposable
{
    public new /*:(*/ Dispose() { ... };
}
```

and the caller uses like

```
using (SomeDisposable sd = SomeDisposableFactory.Create(...))
{
} // Wrapper.Dispose() never called.
```

The `Wrapper.Dispose()` is never called.  If `Dispose()` were virtual then `Wrapper.Dispose()` would be called.

The `IDisposable` interface does not guarantee that the other best practice method `virtual Dispose(bool)` actually exists or enforce that either be virtual so it cannot be generally relied on to exist (it is only a recommended pattern).  Interfaces currently do not allow constraints on virtual.

What are some pros and cons for not making the recommended `Dispose()` pattern virtual which would have solved this particular dilemma.  Should C# allow a way of forcing virtual methods via an interface (since abstract classes aren't popular as contract definitions).

Comment: Found a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619490/why-should-dispose-be-non-virtual)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  The pattern actually says that `Dispose()` (non-virtual) should call a `protected virtual void Dispose(bool)` method.  This guarantees that the base class `Dispose` call can pass up the hierarchy properly.

This is spelled out in the documentation for [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2):

- It should provide one public, non-virtual Dispose() method and a protected virtual Dispose(Boolean disposing) method.
- The Dispose() method must call Dispose(true) and should suppress finalization for performance.
- The base type should not include any finalizers.

Comment: Accepting this answer while wishing the "should's" and "must's" from the docs were specified/enforceable by C# itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is already solved.

Disposable types which are not `sealed` should use the common [dispose pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#basic_pattern):

```
public class DisposableResourceHolder : IDisposable
{
    private SafeHandle resource; // handle to a resource

    public DisposableResourceHolder()
    {
        this.resource = ... // allocates the resource
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // dispose managed resources.
            if (resource != null) resource.Dispose();
        }

        // free unmanaged resources.
    }
}
```

Comment: I see this a lot. This is encouraging people to use finalizers where they are not necessarily needed.  You should explain that the finalizer should only be used if the class has unmanaged resources.  When you add a finalizer, you automatically make the object a long lived object and it will always be elevated to at least a level 1 generation object in the garbage collector.

Comment: @stevethethread excellent point. A derived class can always define their own finalizer if they have the need.

Comment: @stevethethread your point may be valid, but why would i want to implement `IDisposable` if i don't have unmanaged resources?

Comment: Managed resources.  E.g. Database connections etc.  The point of a finalizer is to ensure unmanged resources are cleaned up if dispose has not be called.  Hence why you call GC.SuppressFinalize in your dispose method, as it means Dispose has been called and resource have been cleaned up.

Comment: @stevethethread: The call to `GC.SuppressFinalize()` probably isn't really needed, since the only classes which should define cleanup finalizers are those which derive directly from `System.Object`, but in some cases it may be necessary to ensure that the call to `Dispose` can't get optimized out; `GC.KeepAlive(this)` would be a fine way to do that, but `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` is just as good.