# what's the problem in idisposable pattern implementation withing abstract class

Tags: c#, sonarqube, idisposable

I have following implementation for one of an abstract class but getting warning from sonarqube code analysis

```
public abstract class BackgroundService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private bool _disposedValue;//https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose
    private Task _executingTask;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _stoppingCts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    protected abstract Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken);

    public virtual Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _executingTask = ExecuteAsync(_stoppingCts.Token);

        if (_executingTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            return _executingTask;
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public virtual async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (_executingTask == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            _stoppingCts.Cancel();
        }
        finally
        {
            await Task.WhenAny(_executingTask, Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken));
        }

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected void Dispose(bool disposing)//todo kamran
    {
        if (_disposedValue)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (disposing)
        {
            _stoppingCts.Cancel();
        }            

        _disposedValue = true;
    }

    ~BackgroundService()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

sonar cube error is

> Fix this implementation of 'IDisposable' to conform to the dispose pattern.
> Code Smell
> Provide 'protected' overridable implementation of 'Dispose(bool)' on 'BackgroundService' or mark the type as 'sealed'.
> 'BackgroundService.Dispose()' should not be 'virtual' or 'abstract'.
> 'BackgroundService.Dispose()' should also call 'Dispose(true)'.

Comment: It quite literally says it: `Dispose()` should not be virtual ...

Comment: And Dispose(bool disposing) should be.

Comment: As an aside, if you're writing a class intended for wide use and parallelism is involved somehow, it pays off to make the implementation thread-safe to ensure disposing doesn't happen more than once, because it's very hard for callers to ensure this and far easier if parallel calls to `Dispose` are safe. This is as simple as making the check use `Interlocked.CompareExchange` at the start of your method to do an atomic test-and-set, rather than a simple field assignment.

Comment: For more discussion on why `Dispose()` should *not* be virtual: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619490/why-should-dispose-be-non-virtual#:~:text=The%20Dispose%20method%20should%20not,(%20Dispose(bool)%20).

Comment: @JeroenMostert off-topic to this question, but I always use `Interlocked.Exchange(ref x, 1) == 0`, instead of `CompareExchange`: are there any downsides to making the equality outside and not using `CompareExchange`?

Comment: @Jcl: not that I can think of -- I'm just used to using `CompareExchange` generally because it's more conservative (won't write anything if the expected state isn't encountered) and useful in more scenarios. For this particular one `Exchange` should do just as well since the ultimate value is stable.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks, [this](https://gist.github.com/javiercampos/6e611e10e648c531a553c4494ecd6cb3) is my  `Guard` class, and I've been using it forever, and just made me doubt I could have used it wrong all this time :-)

Comment: @Jcl: well, that class in particular does have a potential problem when you start overlapping calls to `Reset` and `Once`, of course -- you would need additional synchronization if you wanted to be sure of the order of operations (or else be sure that, for example, `Reset` is never called at any point where other threads could be doing `Once`). Add a little more of that and you might as well use a full-blown `Monitor`, which is more flexible. I'm not sure I'd call this class worthy of what it's trying to abstract myself, but that's a personal preference.

Comment: @JeroenMostert yep, I understand the `Reset` problem, and I only use it on very uncommon ocassions (it's a recent addition and only added it for Blazor Server, where the framework takes some lifetime decisions away from me), and properly synced. I see your point there. Anyway, this is off-topic here, thanks for your answer! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Dispose()` method should not be virtual: your `Dispose(bool)` one should be (and it's the one to be overriden by inheritors): it's a common and known pattern where you use the `bool` parameter to know if you are disposing deterministically (by a call to `Dispose` or a `using` block) or via a finalizer (which you haven't implemented in your abstract class, by the way), where you only need to dispose unmanaged references.

You are lacking the finalizer disposing to make the pattern complete:

```cs
~BackgroundService() {
   Dispose(false);
}
```

Otherwise, the `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` makes no sense

Comment: thanks jcl. i have updated the implementation but still getting same sonarqube warning

Comment: @KamranShahid can we see the updated implementation? because if *the same* warning is still there after making `Dispose()` non-virtual, and `Dispose(bool)` virtual, then sonarqube is wrong

Comment: I have updated it in the question. i hope i have correctly implemented as per your suggestion. still getting same warnings

Comment: Nope, your `Dispose(bool)` needs to be `virtual` (`protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)`), as stated in the answer