# ASP.NET: Implementing Init and Dispose methods

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, methods, dispose, init

Can an ASP.NET web application have only one `Init` and one `Dispose` method or can I implement these per class for those which I want to associate such methods?

More specifically I have `Customer` component and a `CustomerRecord` classes and would like to implement `Init` and `Dispose` methods in both of them.

What is the proper way to do this?

**Requirement:**

I want to have independent `Init` and `Dispose` methods for each aforementioned class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For classes that should be disposable, by exposing a public `Dispose` method, the `IDispsable` interface must be implemented for 'disposability' to be effective out of the scope of explicit user disposal. This has been covered many times in many places, [including here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898828/c-finalize-dispose-pattern), for example:

```
public class Customer : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SupressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            //dispose of managed resources
        }
        //dispose of unmanaged resources
    }

    ~Customer()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

Note that the destructor (the method starting with the tilde `~`) may not be necessary, but read the details from the answer I linked above for clarity on the situation of *what* and *why* - this just answers your question directly.

As for an `Init` method, are you referring to a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx)?

If so, then look at the destructor in the above example; a constructor (or initialiser) can be defined in the same way minus the tilde and, generally, plus an explicit access modifier (`public`, `private`, et cetera), for example:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a base class with the Init and Dispose method as you wish and then make the other classes to inherit from it. For example:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public void Init()
    {
        //Some code
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //Some code
    }
}

public class Customer : BaseClass
{
    //Some code
}
```

That might help you.

Comment: I want to have independent init and dispose methods for each class that is mentioned in the question

Comment: Your disposable classes must implement `IDisposable`. Also, methods that are intended to be overridden or extended should be marked appropriately with the `virtual` modifier.