# Dispoable pattern with c#4.0 & vs2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, idisposable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Finalize/Dispose pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898828/c-finalize-dispose-pattern)

How should I go about implementing disposable pattern (IDisposable interface) properly with vs2010 and c#4? A quick example and and important tip would be so nice.

I know there are c#2 examples but asking more for c#4.

Edit: Alright please delete the question (as I cant). I now see that nothing with respect to object disposal have changed since c#2.0 to 4.0

Comment: Adobe what?  You're missing some vital information here....

Comment: Duplicate. Nothing has change with Dispose in C# 4.0 so the answer qes suggests is still valid.

Comment: Can you imagine what the consequences would be on legacy code if Microsoft changed the Dispose pattern for .NET 4?

Comment: @MattDavey: Changing recommended Dispose pattern for future code wouldn't have to break legacy code.  There are some defects in Microsoft's pattern (e.g. it requires every level of a hierarchy to maintain its own "isDisposed" flag, and it wrongly encourages classes to be designed for the possibility of child classes adding a Finalize routine for cleanup); the only problem I could see would be that a programmer who inherits from an old class might expect it to provide a DisposeBegun flag when it doesn't, but that should be easy enough to deal with when it happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way as in previous versions of C#. The recommended pattern goes along those lines:

```
class MyClass : IDisposable
{

    ~MyClass()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private bool disposed = false;
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // Dispose managed resources
            }
            // Dispose unmanaged resources

            disposed = true;
        }
    }

}
```

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

The basic pattern.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Dispose Method
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deconstructor
    /// </summary>
    ~[PutYourClassHere]()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// IDisposable Implementation
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">Disposing Flag</param>
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            //Free Managed Resources
        }

        //Free Native Resources 
    }
```