# Connection Pooling : How to implement IDisposable correctly to return TCP connection back to pool

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I'm trying to implement TCP connection pooling and return a connection back to the pool using IDisposable. I'm wondering if my implementation is correct, it seems to be working but I think because the base class also implements IDisposable and finalize, my code might be leaky.

```
 public class BaseClass : IDisposable
 {
    internal bool IsDisposed { get; set; }
    private object someResource;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~BaseClass()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (someResource != null)
        {
            // some clearn up
            return;
        }

        if (disposing)
        {
            //dispose un managed resources

        }
    }
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    // adds some functionality
}

public class MyClass : ChildClass, IDisposable
{
    MyPoolManager manager = null;

    public MyClass(MyPoolManager manager)
    {
        this.manager = manager;

    }
    public new void Dispose()
    {
        manager.ReturnPooledConnection(this);
    }
}

public class MyPoolManager
{
    private static MyPoolManager instance = new MyPoolManager();
    private static object objLock = new object();

    private static Queue<MyClass> que = null;
    private string name;

    static MyPoolManager()
    {
        que = new Queue<MyClass>();
        // enqueue some instances of MyClass here
        MyClass client = new MyClass(instance);
        que.Enqueue(client);
    }

    private MyPoolManager() { }

    public MyPoolManager(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public MyClass GetPooledConnection()
    {
        lock (objLock)
        {
            while (que.Count == 0)
            {
                if (!Monitor.Wait(objLock, 1000))
                    throw new TimeoutException("Connection timeout");
            }
            return que.Dequeue();
        }
    }

    public void ReturnPooledConnection(MyClass client)
    {
        lock (objLock)
        {
            que.Enqueue(client);
            Monitor.Pulse(objLock);
        }
    }
}
```

**And you would use it like this in your program :**

```
 MyPoolManager pool = new MyPoolManager();
 using (var conn = pool.GetPooledConnection())
 {
      // use the conn here
 }

 // when you reach here the conn should have returned back to the pool
```

Comment: What type of connection are we talking about here?

Comment: +1 @MaciejDopieralski This is a good question because .NET already has a database connection pooling mechanism...

Comment: a tcp-ip connection open to a remote server.

Answer (score -1):

MyClass shouldn't define new Dispose(), because indeed it can lead to leaked resources (if it doesn't call `base.Dispose()`).

Instead, you can use another class:

```
public class MyClassWrapper : IDisposable
{
    MyPoolManager manager = null;
    MyClass myClass = null;

    public MyClassWrapper(MyPoolManager manager, MyClass myClass)
    {
        this.manager = manager;
        this.myClass = myClass;

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        manager.ReturnPooledConnection(this.myClass);
    }

    public MyClass GetMyClass()
    {
         return this.myClass;
    }
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/898867/724944) is a great post on SO about implementing IDisposable

Comment: if i call base.Dispose() then wouldn't it be disposed off? I just want the object to return back to the pool, i'll be reusing it again.

Comment: You're right, that doesn't make sense. But if you inherit from IDisposable then you should call base.Dispose to avoid leaking resources. I think you should make a wrapper (composition) around your connection that doesn't inherit from BaseClass. I'll edit my post

Comment: actually, i don't need to call base.dispose() because the object is never being disposed, it's being sent back to the pool. And since the app pool will stay alive till the app runs, the finalizer will kick in and dispose of the objects when the app shuts down.

Comment: I guess... but It's difficult to understand at first glance and you should document it with more comments (things we discussed here)