# Guidelines For Dispose() and Ninject

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, ninject, idisposable

So, I have a method exposed from a WCF service as such:

```
public GetAllCommentsResponse GetAllComments(GetAllCommentsRequest request)
{
    var response = new GetAllCommentsResponse();

    using(_unitOfWork)
        try
        {
            Guard.ArgNotNull(request, "request");

            var results = _unitOfWork.CommentRepository.Get(d => d.Id > 0).ToArray();

            //... Do rest of stuff here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.Success = false;
            response.FailureInformation = ex.Message;
            Logger.LogError("GetAllComments Method Failed", ex);
        }

    return response;
}
```

I have a global DataUnitOfWork object (which implements IDisposable) that gets instantiated by Ninject through a constructor argument when a service call comes in. When debugging, if I use

```
using(_unitOfWork)
```

the _unitOfWork object gets disposed immediately after going out of scope then gets called again by Ninject (although it's been marked as disposed, so nothing happens.) Without the using statement, Ninject handles the disposing.

Long story short, is there a general rule of thumb for this? I've been scared of the whole IDisposable thing after everything I read seems to indicate never to use it, or use it in certain eclectic situations, but it's always confused me.

Any input is appreciated.

Oh, also while I'm here typing anyway, why exactly is there a call to GC.SuppressFinalize() when disposing? How do Dispose and Finalize differ?

Comment: Found answer in similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898828/c-sharp-finalize-dispose-pattern

Comment: The `SuppressFinalize` tells the GC system 'Don't worry about calling `Finalize` when you've determined the object is garbage as we've already performed the cleanup thanks to someone explicityl calling `Dispose` on it. If you don't do this, the object remains on the finalizer queue and Dispose _will_ get called again from the Finalizer thread.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The CLR documentation states that whoever creates a Disposable object is responsible for calling Dispose. In this case the object is created by Ninject. That means you should *not* call Dispose explicitly.

Ninject disposes every Disposable object that has another scope other than `InTransientScope` [as soon as the scope object to which the created object is tied is collected by GC](https://web.archive.org/web/20130111064153/http://kohari.org/2009/03/06/cache-and-collect-lifecycle-management-in-ninject-20/). That's why every Disposable object should be `Bind`d with a scope that is not `InTransientScope()`. E.g. you can use `InParentScope()` from [the NamedScope extension](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.namedscope/wiki) which will Dispose the object as soon as the object it is injected into is garbage collected.

Comment: Which means that in InRequestScope's `IDisposable` objects will be disposed at the end of the request?

Comment: Yes, assuming you've done everything right, including using the OncePerWebRequest module

Comment: As far as I can tell ninject never disposes InSingletonScope either.

Comment: InSingletonScope is Disposed when the Kernel is Disposed. https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes
This should work:

using(IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel())  {
....
}

Comment: worth noting that "InTransientScope" is the default scope when none is provided: https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes