# Passing DB context as parameter in mvc

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it the best way to pass context object as parameter to another C# method?

Can somebody advise, passing it this way will lead to any issues ??

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Passing a DbContext as a parameter isn't a problem at all -- there's nothing particularly special about it.  It's just another class.

The only issue that jumps to mind is one that would be the same for any IDisposable -- the .NET developer guidelines recommend that only the class responsible for creating the IDisposable should dispose of it.

...that can be tricky to determine if you are using a dependency injection framework (eg Ninject) as it is sort of a mystery to any of the code written by the application where the objects are created.

To that end, you should never bind an IDisposable object in TransientScope:

[Guidelines For Dispose() and Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234802/guidelines-for-dispose-and-ninject)