# Globalization incorrectly uses default culture in all scenarios after deployment

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis-8, globalization, windows-server-2012-r2

Local Environment:
Win10 x64
VS 2015 Pro Update 3
IIS 10.0 Express

Production Environment:
Win server 2012 R2
IIS 8.5

Im developing an ASP.NET 4.6.1 MVC app that needs to be supported in english, danish, and dutch. I implement the neutral cultures as im only interested in the language and not in specifics.
I use satellite assemblies (as some would call them) or rather Resource.resx files for my translations. First approach i followed [this often referenced post](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx) and it works perfectly *locally*. As soon as i deploy it to the production environment translations stop working. I set the threads according to database values: [image: Initialize method in HomeController]
And i have verified that this method is always correctly executed in the production environment. I have tried setting the threads like in the referenced post as well which also works fine locally, but not in production. And i have even tried setting it directly as the top of my views using razor to no avail.
What strikes me as really odd is that i had it working once in the production environment after i did some fiddling, but im pretty sure i didnt really do anything and suddenly it worked. Sadly it stopped working after i deployed an update to the app, and i havent been able to get it to work since. I have since tried messing with all settings in the .NET environment on the IIS for this website and for the root directory:
[image: .NET globalization settings]
But even specifying *da-DK* or *da* as the culture here or directly in the web.config of my app or hardcoding the thread to use *da* as the culture doesnt help at all. Funny thing is that number and date formatting correctly changes. So it doesnt seem to be an issue with the thread not having its culture changed, but rather IIS refusing to use the other resource files. When deployed the folder structure has the *da* folder in *bin* and it contains a file named *Resources.resources.resx* which i believe is correct. I tried having the resource files located in a class library as the article suggests, but also in a folder in the same project out of frustration. The resource files are set to public accessibility and are compiled as Embedded Resources without copying files.

So my question is, how come IIS refuses to use any other resource file than the default? And how is it possible that it worked *once* ? At this point im considering just taking translations to the database, because at least that works. What suggestions do you have? I believe the .NET environment on the IIS has all the necessary languages installed as they are visible in the .NET globalization settings, but i might be wrong?

Update: I tried as suggested by NightOwl, again it works locally(VS debugging) and even if i host the deployed files in iisexpress on my machine. But it still fails on the production environment. The method suggested is similar to [this](https://ruijarimba.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/asp-net-mvc-localization-generate-resource-files-and-localized-views-using-custom-templates/) but still without success. Im starting to think the solution is to upgrade to iis 10 in the production environment.

Comment: Please post a code instead of a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the Nuget package SimpleImpersonation, which appears to change the culture of the current thread behind the scenes. It seems like it changes it back to default after it is disposed, but as i was setting the culture while while the reference was valid, it always defaulted back to en-US. It is still weird that it worked locally in IIS Express 10.0. But at least now it works for both environments...

Answer (score 0):

That article seems to have some pre-MVC ideas in mind:

- Resource files are not supported fully in MVC (at least not without hacks) - see [Resource Files and ASP.NET MVC Projects](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx). However, you can use [embedded resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2c9s1d7(v=vs.100).aspx) or use a [ResourceManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager(v=vs.110).aspx) to load external resources.
- Setting user language according to browser settings is usually the wrong choice. Instead, you should use the URL to pass the culture information so search engines can crawl and index them. Localization is *content* not *personalization*. Relying on headers to display the right language can be frustrating to users that are sitting behind firewalls that change those headers. Using the URL to choose language gives direct control over the language to the user.

See my answer to [ASP.NET MVC 5 culture in route and url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32839796/181087) for a pure MVC way to do localization.

Basically, the answer to your question is in the [this link](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx) - by default resources in `App_GlobalResources` are internal and cannot be used without modification to the settings. They require special attention during deployment or they will not be deployed with your application. `App_LocalResources` are not supported in MVC at all (they are for legacy ASP.NET pages). In short: avoid `App_GlobalResources` and `App_LocalResources` (which has its own set of problems) in MVC.

> **Off-topic:** It looks like you are also using a base controller (because of the `Initialize` method). This tightly couples your application together. A better way is to use global filters, which can each contain a single piece of functionality. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221865/questions-about-using-ninject/36224308#36224308).

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, i think you missed a few points. The article is specifically about MVC and is referenced in many other SO posts. I did initially use a separate class library for the .resx files, but tried out of desparation to place them in the same project. App_LocalResources was just an inspiration from somewhere, it isnt actually related to non-MVC stuff in this case. I will update my question to better reflect that. 
Cookies vs urls are super irrelevant to this case, it wont change anything. I get my culture names from a database. I dont think filters will change anything?

Comment: `The article is specifically about MVC and is referenced in many other SO posts.` - I realize that, but unfortunately the author is using a lot of pre-MVC ideas in the article, and has led you astray. Filters will change something - it makes you do it the MVC way instead of copying old (bad) habits from ASP.NET and tightly-coupling your code together.

Comment: I tried the method suggested in your link which is the same as this https://ruijarimba.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/asp-net-mvc-localization-generate-resource-files-and-localized-views-using-custom-templates/ i believe. Again it works perfectly when debugging, and i even tried hosting the deployed files in iisexpress 10 (on my machine) and that works flawlessly aswell. The server however still ignores it. Im starting to think my issues would be solved by upgrading to iis 10.