# How to set C# object to null itself

Tags: c#, null

In C++, it is possible to delete `this` and set its own reference to null.

I want to set an object instance to null itself.

```
public class Foo
{

    public void M( )
    {
       // this = null; // How do I do this kind of thing?
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want the object to set itself to null? Wouldn't it be better to do it in the place the object is used?

Comment: You can only set references that point to the object to null.

Comment: This doesn't make sense, the only purpose it would serve is to prevent usage of 'this'. All the other references would still point to the instance.

Comment: are you sure you need that? it is not possible in c#, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to use it like example usage below:Foo f= new Foo();
            
            f.M();

            if (f==null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("somethig to do");
            }

Comment: Why? I agree that you'd want to set it where it is used.

Comment: I want to use it like example usage below:Foo f= new Foo(); f.M(); if (f==null) { Console.WriteLine("somethig to do"); }

Comment: You cannot call `f.M()` if `f` is `null`. This simply doesn't make any sense. Your program will crash much before the `M` method is invoked. It makes strictly no sense to check inside the `M` method if the current instance is null because you wouldn't even be able to call this method if this is the case.

Comment: I want to set current reference to null in M(). then I will control if it is null

Comment: You don't have access to the variable that holds a reference to `f` from within `M()`. You just don't. Find another way to achieve your goal. Or, tell us what that goal is.

Comment: @SonerGönül You're right, I should have posted this as a comment to the original question.

Comment: In C++, "delete this" like operation is allowed. I want to do that kind of usage in c#

Comment: You can't. End of story. Sorry. Why do you want to do this? What's your use case? We might be able to help with that.

Comment: I am trying to use it in a binary search tree recursive implementation. I need =null or Dispose or etc in C#

Comment: Well, now, dispose you can do! [Very common](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898828/c-sharp-finalize-dispose-pattern) [pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) in .NET.

Comment: IDisposable only adds dispose method.  I could not dispose current instance in M(). public class Foo : IDisposable 
    {

        public void M()
        {
            //this =null;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
             
        }
    }

Comment: I really do recommend that **you tell us what larger problem you're trying to solve**. You keep circling back to deleting an object from within itself, without telling us why. Maybe read the links I posted, and come back if they don't trigger any ideas. But **tell us why you think you need to do this**. Be expansive.

Comment: ok. I pasted my whole code to http://pastie.org/5566607 it it my binary search tree implementation. i can not remove root node. I also read the dispose pattern. I do not want to call any other methods like obj.dispose()

Comment: If you're sure you want to, then have another object (a `Tree` class or something) hold a reference to the root node. Null it out from there.

Comment: there should be a wrapper for this node class to achive its goal but actually I am trying to find a "delete this" equivalent in c# like c++.

Comment: You can't. Find another way. We're not lying to you.

Comment: sure. thanks a lot for your answers and also patience.

Comment: Don't use the comments to improve your question. Also don't post the code somewhere else. Just add it to your question. This helps others to understand your problem without reading through a long list of comments. People cannot even answer your question in a proper way if any hints leading to an answer are hidden somewhere in the comments.

Comment: @user1924210: For completeness, the definitive answer is Raymond Chen's blog post [When does an object become eligible for garbage collection?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/10/10048149.aspx) You might also want to read the related [Everybody thinks about garbage collection the wrong way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/09/10047586.aspx).

Answer (score 9):

`this` is actually just a special name given to the parameter, `arg0`, in an instance method. Setting it to `null` is *not allowed*:

1. you cannot ever change `this` for instance methods on a `class`
2. you *can* change `this` for instance methods on a `struct`, but you can't assign `null`

The reason for 1. is that it **would not be useful**:

- the parameter `arg0` is by-val (not by-ref) on `class` instance methods, so the method's caller won't notice the change (for completeness: `arg0` is by-ref on `struct` instance methods)
- it won't really change memory management in any way:

  - setting something to `null` does not delete it; the GC handles that
  - if there are *external* roots holding a reference to the object, they will *still* be holding a reference to the object
  - if you are worried about the edge-case of the parameter being the last root to the object, then just *exit the method*

So basically, that syntax is not allowed, because it doesn't do what you want. There is **no** C# metaphor for what you want.

Answer (score 8):

This is not possible in .NET. You cannot set the current instance to null from within the object itself. In .NET the current instance (`this`) is readonly, you cannot assign a value to it. And by the way that's not something you would even need in .NET.

Comment: is not there any way to make current reference to null apart from this keyword

Comment: No, there is no way to do this from within the object itself. Why do you want to do this from within the object?

Answer (score 3):

In C++ `delete this` frees the memory of the object. There is no equivalent to that in C# (or any other .NET language). Although it is allowed in C++ I don't think it's a good practice. At least [you have to be very careful](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/delete-this.html).

.NET uses [garbage collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/0xy59wtx.aspx) instead to free memory. Once an object isn't referenced any more and cannot be accessed from anywhere in your code the garbage collector can [eventually](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee787088.aspx#conditions_for_a_garbage_collection) free the memory (and the garbage collector **is** careful). So just lean back and let the garbage collector do its work.

Comment: I think you should replace "will" with "can" in the sentance *Once an object isn't referenced ... the garbage collector will free the memory*. The way you wrote it makes it sound like deallocation is more deterministic than it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Simply no. As this is not possible to access a method from a null object. In your case you want say

```
F f = new F() // where f = null
f.SomeMethod(); // ?????? not possible
```

In this case you get a Null Reference Exception. You can see Darin's Comment and Explanation too on the same.
How could you access anything from null, which means nothing. I have no idea about legacy but .Net does not provides you such things. Instead you can set it to null when its not needed anymore.

Ex From MSDN

```
public class Node<T>
{
        // Private member-variables
        private T data;
        private NodeList<T> neighbors = null;

        public Node() {}
        public Node(T data) : this(data, null) {}
        public Node(T data, NodeList<T> neighbors)
        {
            this.data = data;
            this.neighbors = neighbors;
        }

        public T Value
        {
            get
            {
                return data;
            }
            set
            {
                data = value;
            }
        }

        protected NodeList<T> Neighbors
        {
            get
            {
                return neighbors;
            }
            set
            {
                neighbors = value;
            }
        }
    }
}


public class NodeList<T> : Collection<Node<T>>
{
    public NodeList() : base() { }

    public NodeList(int initialSize)
    {
        // Add the specified number of items
        for (int i = 0; i < initialSize; i++)
            base.Items.Add(default(Node<T>));
    }

    public Node<T> FindByValue(T value)
    {
        // search the list for the value
        foreach (Node<T> node in Items)
            if (node.Value.Equals(value))
                return node;

        // if we reached here, we didn't find a matching node
        return null;
    }
}

 and Right—that operate on the base class's Neighbors property.
public class BinaryTreeNode<T> : Node<T>
{
    public BinaryTreeNode() : base() {}
    public BinaryTreeNode(T data) : base(data, null) {}
    public BinaryTreeNode(T data, BinaryTreeNode<T> left, BinaryTreeNode<T> right)
    {
        base.Value = data;
        NodeList<T> children = new NodeList<T>(2);
        children[0] = left;
        children[1] = right;

        base.Neighbors = children;
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode<T> Left
    {
        get
        {
            if (base.Neighbors == null)
                return null;
            else
                return (BinaryTreeNode<T>) base.Neighbors[0];
        }
        set
        {
            if (base.Neighbors == null)
                base.Neighbors = new NodeList<T>(2);

            base.Neighbors[0] = value;
        }
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode<T> Right
    {
        get
        {
            if (base.Neighbors == null)
                return null;
            else
                return (BinaryTreeNode<T>) base.Neighbors[1];
        }
        set
        {
            if (base.Neighbors == null)
                base.Neighbors = new NodeList<T>(2);

            base.Neighbors[1] = value;
        }
    }
}


public class BinaryTree<T>
{
   private BinaryTreeNode<T> root;

   public BinaryTree()
   {
      root = null;
   }

   public virtual void Clear()
   {
      root = null;
   }

   public BinaryTreeNode<T> Root
   {
      get
      {
         return root;
      }
      set
      {
         root = value;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Firstly this was working as c++ code. I did not need any wrapper. I operated on node class. I ported it to c# but I could not find any "delete this" equivalent to implement. I read msdn BST article before.