# Cache to map IntPtr handles to C# class instances in pinvoke callbacks

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke, weak-references, finalizer

I'm writing a C# wrapper around a native dll that uses opaque pointers to identify resources. A typical example would be something like

```
typedef struct session session;
typedef struct track track;

void* sessionCreate(int arg, session** sess);
void  sessionRelease(session** sess);
track* sessionGetTrack(session* sess, int index);
void trackAddRef(track* trk);
void trackRelease(track* trk);
int  trackGetLength(track* trk);
```

In my wrapper, I've created C# classes corresponding to the different opaque types, with member functions corresponding to the various functions using the different opaque types.

This is fine. There are also callbacks from the dll, for example

```
void(* track_changed )(track *trk, bool changedExternally);
```

In order to map from the static delegate that handles the callback to the object that corresponds to the handle supplied, I'm using a static dictionary of WeakReferences (IntPtr/SafeHandle as key, object reference as aata) in each of my classes.

So what is the right way to approach removing entries from the static dictionary? I'm writing library code and cannot rely on my clients to Dispose my objects. Should the I put the code in the finalizer?

Or is there a better way to manage the correspondence between the static callbacks and my object instances?

Answer (score 1):

Your clients *really should* (indeed I would prefer to say *must*) dispose of your objects since they are `IDisposable`, just like they do with other BCL classes.

In any case a bog-standard implementation of the [dispose/finalize pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx) should cover all bases. There is more related discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898828/c-sharp-finalize-dispose-pattern).

Comment: Asking clients to have to Dispose my objects simply because of my internal implementation details seems like bad form to me. I'd rather not implement IDisposable at all, and just leave the Finalizers to remove entries from the static dictionary. Would this be bad?

Comment: I was under the impression that each object corresponds to (or is?) a `SafeHandle`, which is rightly `IDisposable`. Therefore shouldn't the user have the responsibility of releasing the unmanaged resource as usual? When they do, you can depopulate the dictionary for free.

Comment: Part of the motivation for the facade/wrapper is to make use of garbage collection so that users need not worry about manual resource handling. Deterministic releasing of the unmanaged resources is not important to clients of this wrapper.

Comment: @TomDavies - If you want users to be able to use the garbage collector then you should implement IDisposable.  Don't try to recreate something custom, use IDisposable, and allow your users to implement your libary the correct way.

Comment: Ramhound - that confuses me - implementing IDisposible suggests to users that they should take responsibility for the lifecycle of the objects, rather than the GC. At least, it looks that way to me.

Comment: @TomDavies: It's not only about *deterministic* release. Applications that use lots of unmanaged resources might easily starve the OS itself. IMHO the cleanliness of a dictionary is not what you should be worrying about -- you can put 50K items inside with nothing bad happening other than memory being used. But 50K unreleased OS handles?

Comment: They are not OS handles in this case, but handles to refernce counted structures allocated/destroyed inside a native dll. I don't really see any difference between leaving the cleanup of these resources to the GC, and the normal operation of the GC on managed objects.