# Autofac DbContext has been disposed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac, ioc-container

I've read this post [DbContext has been disposed and autofac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919543/dbcontext-has-been-disposed-and-autofac) but I'm still getting the same error:

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

```
public class EFRepository : IRepository
{
    private EFDbContext context;

    public EFRepository(EFDbContext ctx)
    {
        context = ctx;
    }

    public TEntity FirstOrDefault<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
        where TEntity : class, IContextEntity
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = includes.Aggregate<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>, IQueryable<TEntity>>
                     (context.Set<TEntity>(), (current, expression) => current.Include(expression));            

        return query.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    }
}
```

And in the Global.asax

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

builder.Register<IRepository>(c => new EFRepository(new EFDbContext()));

ILifetimeScope container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

Controller injection:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository repository;
    private readonly IMembershipService membershipService;        

    public AccountController(IRepository repo, IMembershipService mmbrSvc)
    {
        repository = repo;
        membershipService = mmbrSvc;
    }
    [HttpPost]        
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)             
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);            

        string returnUrl = (string)TempData["ReturnUrl"];
        LoginDto accountDto = viewModel.GetLoginStatus(repository, membershipService, returnUrl);
        string accountDtoJson = JsonHelper.Serialize(accountDto);

        return Content(accountDtoJson, "application/json");
    }
}
```

Then in LoginViewModel:

```
public LoginDto GetLoginStatus(IRepository repo, IMembershipService mmbrSvc, string returnUrl)
    {
        repository = repo;
        membershipService = mmbrSvc;

        User user = repository.FirstOrDefault<User>(x => x.Username == Username, x => x.Membership);
    ............
    ............
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to register the `DbContext` itself with AutoFac and give it the appropriate lifetime. `InstancePerDependency` is usually fine for repositories.

```
builder.RegisterType<EFDbContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerDependency();
```

Then, you don't need to give the repository registration an object, just register the type (remembering to specify the lifetime as well):

```
builder.Register<EFRepository>().As<IRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: Steve thanks for the suggestion, I tried 
    builder.RegisterType<EFDbContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerDependency();
            builder.RegisterType<EFRepository>().As<IRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

But still getting the same error.

Comment: @AlexanderC.how are you actually calling the repository method?

Comment: through controller dependency injection as well as dependency injection in other services
builder.RegisterType<BusinessTransactionService>().As<IBusinessTransactionService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

Comment: @AlexanderC.can you update your question with an example of your controller constructor and repository call.

Comment: @AlexanderC.maybe try changing your `DbContext` registration to `InstancePerLifetimeScope` as well.

Comment: I tried that as well and it didn't work. I decided not to inject DbContext into repository but wrap code inside public TEntity FirstOrDefault<TEntity> with Using(var context = new DbContext()) and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use
`builder.RegisterType<EFDbContext>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();`