# Running a async method as a Quartz.NET job and disposed object issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await, quartz.net, quartz.net-2.0

I'm using Quartz.NET in this context (needs to mention that `GrabberContext` is a `DbContext` extended class):

```
// configuring Autofac:
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// configuring GrabberContext
builder.RegisterType<GrabberContext>()
    .AsSelf()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

// configuring GrabService
builder.RegisterType<GrabService>()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

// configuring Quartz to use Autofac
builder.RegisterModule(new QuartzAutofacFactoryModule());
builder.RegisterModule(new QuartzAutofacJobsModule(typeof(DiConfig).Assembly));

var container = builder.Build();

// configuring jobs:
var scheduler = container.Resolve<IScheduler>();
scheduler.Start();
var jobDetail = new JobDetailImpl("GrabJob", null, typeof(GrabJob));
var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("GrabJobTrigger")
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
        .RepeatForever()
        .WithIntervalInMinutes(1)
    )
    .StartAt(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(30))
    .Build();
    scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```

and this is the job:

```
public class GrabJob : IJob {

    private readonly IGrabService _grabService;

    public GrabJob(IGrabService grabService) { _grabService = grabService; }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context) {
        _grabService.CrawlNextAsync("");
    }

}
```

The `GrabService` implementation is something like this:

```
public class GrabService : IGrabService {

    private readonly GrabberContext _context;

    public GrabService(GrabberContext context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task CrawlNextAsync(string group) {
        try {
            var feed = await _context.MyEntities.FindAsync(someId); // line #1
            // at the line above, I'm getting the mentioned error...
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

But when the execution gets to `line #1` I get this error:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used
>   for operations that require a connection.

Any idea please?

Comment: where you have set the connection string ?

Comment: Can you show the AutoFac registration for IGrabService ?

Comment: @stuartd see the update please

Comment: There are existing questions around this area which may help - [this on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35422549/autofac-dbcontext-has-been-disposed) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919543/dbcontext-has-been-disposed-and-autofac) for example

Comment: @Javad_Amiry: Does the exception occur with *just* the code you've posted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling the async method `CrawlNextAsync()` from a sync method `Execute()`.  As soon as `CrawlNextAsync()` hits ...`await _context`..., it returns, and `Execute()` then returns, and I assume at that point the `GrabJob`, and hence `GrabService`, and hence `GrabberContext`, is disposed, while the continuation in `CrawlNextAsync()` continues (and tries to use the disposed `GrabberContext`).

As a simple fix, you could try change

```
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context) {
    _grabService.CrawlNextAsync("");
}
```

to

```
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context) {
    _grabService.CrawlNextAsync("").Wait();
}
```

Comment: I did the exact thing and it worked. thanks to the try. cheers