# AutoFac Request-scope is not WHOLE request

Tags: c#, entity-framework, autofac, dbcontext

I just set up AutoFac in my MVC project and set my EF DbContext to `InstancePerRequest`. Until now DbContext has been a static singleton. It seems that AutoFac's "request" scope is not really the entire request. I'm getting the error message:

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

Much like [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35422549/autofac-dbcontext-has-been-disposed) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919543/dbcontext-has-been-disposed-and-autofac/14920567) questions.

I would expect the context to be disposed after the entire request has been handled, but the exception is showing up when I try to access lazily loaded properties in views or return statements.

An example of the problem:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetLotoLockNumbers(int permitId)
{
    var lockNums = lockService.FindLotoLockNumbers(permitId);

    // this line throws an exception because... (go to last line)
    return Json(string.Join(", ", lockNums), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}

public IEnumerable<string> FindLotoLockNumbers(int permitId)
{
    // returns an attached entity
    var permit = Repository.GetDBEntityWithId<PermPermit>(permitId);
    return GetLotoLockNumsForPermit(permit).AsEnumerable();
}

private IEnumerable<string> GetLotoLockNumsForPermit(PermPermit permit, int? configLockItemId = null)
{
    // lazily accesses virtual properties
    var lotoLockItems = permit.permitSections.SelectMany(section => section.childs.Where(
        (sectionItem) => IsLotoLockSectionItem(sectionItem, configLockItemId))).AsEnumerable();
    return lotoLockItems.SelectMany(item => LotoLockHelper.ParseLockNums(item.value)).AsEnumerable();
}

private bool IsLotoLockSectionItem(PermPermitSectionItem item, int? configLockItemId = null)
{
    // ...the context has been exposed when this line gets lazily executed
    return lockItemIds.Contains(item.confSectionItem.id);
}
```

My favourite solution would be if I could simply extend the scope of the context so that it lasts for the whole request (a `singleton` is not ok). Otherwise, I'll have to make changes throughout the code to make sure that everything is loaded before controller actions `return`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was all wrong about AutoFac. The problem in the code here is not that the query's execution is deferred, it's that the `lockItemIds` object is an `IEnumerable` who's execution gets deferred. I loaded the list and stored it in a static variable using an old context and didn't realize that it wasn't executed immediately.

AutoFac's request scope is perfect.

The lesson is: use the debugger to make sure you know exactly which object is causing the problem and check your static variables.