# Enumerate list in finalizer

Tags: c#, finalizer

I have a class that holds on to a list of unmanaged resources. These should be cleaned up in the finalizer, to make sure nothing is leaked. However, they are contained in a `List<IntPtr>.` I have a couple of questions to this situation:

- Am I correct in assuming it is unsafe to enumerate the list in the
  finalizer, because it is possible that the list has already been
  garbage collected?
- Is the only other way to wrap each individual resource in a class that implements a finalizer, thus adding a much larger pressure on the garbage collector? And then the list would store this class?

Comment: Consider using `SafeHandle`.

Comment: Seems there is a [SafeBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safebuffer(v=vs.110).aspx) class just for this purpose.

Comment: No; `SafeBuffer` does not help here.

Comment: The IntPtrs the list contains are pointers to unmanaged memory allocated by Marshal.AllocHGlobal. Creating a derived class of SafeBuffer that allocates with Marshal.AllocHGlobal and frees with Marshal.FreeHGlobal, and then store those instances in the list instead, would solve the problem.

Comment: Yes; deriving it would help.

Comment: However, my question is if I can safely enumerate a list from a finalizer, or not. If I can, I would rather do that than use a ton of SafeBuffer objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20167998/553294. Here supercat states that:

> If an object has an active finalizer, then if the GC would collect it (but for the existence of the finalizer), the GC will instead add it to a queue of objects whose finalizers should be run ASAP and, having done so, de-activate it. The reference within the queue will prevent the GC from collecting the object until the finalizer has run; once the finalizer finishes, if no other references exist to the object and it hasn't re-registered its finalizer, it will cease to exist.

So an object is considered reachable while in the finalization queue, which means the inner list is considered reachable as well. Thus, it is safe to access the list from the finalizer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note about Finalize Guidelines

> An object's Finalize method should free any external resources that
>   the object owns. Moreover, a Finalize method should **release only
>   resources that the object has held onto**. The Finalize method should
>   **not reference any other objects**.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.100).aspx

Finalize and Dispose guidelines are located toward the bottom of the article

Comment: So this means that if I need to allocate thousands of small sections of unmanaged memory, the only way to do that is by putting an enormous pressure on the garbage collector, by having thousands of objects with finalizers?

Comment: @Janiels I do not believe it does, I mainly wanted to point out that creating objects within the finalizer may prevent your object from being garbage collected.  If you however create a list of allocations/pointers that your object owns, you need to implement the IDisposable pattern so the dispose method takes care of the resources both managed and unmanaged following a pattern the garbage collector and the framework expect.

Comment: It says that the finalizer "should release only resources that the object has held onto" - does this include other objects, or are these not considered resources? If not, then the latter "The finalize method should not reference any other objects" applies, and I should not reference a List from the finalizer.

Comment: @Janiels Framework Design Guidelines by Brad Abrams and Krzystof Cwalina also suggest to use SafeHandle whenever possible to manage resources.... section 9.4.2 (pg329) has some great information...

Comment: @Janiels I believe it primarily reference the objects that the object was responsible for creating.  In other words if your object did not create the allocation in memory it would not be a good idea for the object to de-allocate it since it may be in use by another object.

Comment: I am still not convinced that the list cannot be freed before the finalizer uses it.