# Finalize/Dispose pattern in dotnet

Tags: dispose

Why do we use `Dispose(false)`?

Below code in Dispose pattern?

```
~MyClass ()
{
       Dispose(false);
}
```

What happens if I use `Dispose(true)` instead?
What happens If I skip this finalizer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finalize/Dispose pattern in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898828/finalize-dispose-pattern-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

The idea of overriding the Finalize method using Destructurs (~) is to get the ability to dispose manage code or not. In your example you are passing false which is meant dispose managed resource. In the following example you can see it clearly. **Note**: See how I prevent call the Dispose method several times by using the private member "disposed".

```
public class Dog : IDisposable
{
    // Prevent dispose from happening more than once
    private bool disposed = false;

    // IDisposable.Dispose
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Explicitly dispose of resources
        DoDispose(true);

        // Tell GC not to finalize us--we've already done it manually
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    // Function called via Dispose method or via Finalizer
    protected virtual void DoDispose(bool explicitDispose)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            // Free some resources only when invoking via Dispose
            if (explicitDispose)
                FreeManagedResources();   // Define this method

            // Free unmanaged resources here--whether via Dispose
            //   or via finalizer
            FreeUnmanagedResources();

            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    // Finalizer
    ~Dog()
    {
        DoDispose(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, any time code is finished with an object that implements `IDisposable`, it would ensure that the object's `Dispose` method gets called before it is abandoned.  Sometimes, however, objects which implement `IDisposable` get abandoned without being properly disposed.

Classes in .NET can ask the system to watch over instances and let them know if they seem to have been abandoned.  This is done by overriding a method called `Finalize` which is part of type `Object`.  If that method is overridden and has not been suppressed, and the system notices that an object would be eligible collection if not for the presence of an active finalizer, the system will move the system to a queue of objects whose `Finalize` method should run as soon as practical and suppress further observations of the object (so the object will get one shot at running its `Finalize` method, but after that will be eligible for collection).

For some reason I don't understand, the creators of C# decided to forbid programmers using that language from overriding the `Finalize` method directly.  Instead, it requires that they use a special syntax which in turn instructs the compiler to override `Finalize`.  A block of code marked with `~ClassName` will execute when the system notices an object has been abandoned and runs its `Finalize` method.