# Can a class implementing IDisposable be a managed resource?

Tags: c#, idisposable

I'm studying the **standard Dispose pattern**.

I'm looking at [the example on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-6.0#examples) and I have a question.

Looking at the example, there are the following parts.

```cs
...

// Other managed resource this class uses.
private Component component = new Component();

...
```

I learned that unmanaged resources should implement `IDisposable`.

The `Component` class implements `IDisposable`. But why a managed resource?

Comment: tHE "standard" dispose pattern is only for types that hold unmanaged handles. For managed types you do not need and should not implement a finalizer

Comment: @Charlieface So what's the term for a dispose pattern involving only managed resources?

Comment: Not sure there is one, it's just `IDisposable` without a finalizer. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/898867/14868997 and https://vkontech.com/the-dispose-pattern-step-by-step/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create a class that implements `IDisposable` then instances of that class are managed resources. "Managed" basically means .NET. If you create a .NET class then it is managed by definition. Generally speaking, you implement `IDisposable` when your type holds references to other managed resources, i.e. instances of other .NET types that implement `IDisposable`, or unmanaged resources. Unmanaged resources are things that belong to the OS, like file handles, window handles, etc.

It's fairly rare that you will hold unmanaged resources directly but, for instance, it's possible that you might call a Windows API function that returns a handle retrieved directly from the OS that you need to explicitly release. More often, you will hold managed resources that are types from the framework itself and they will hold unmanaged resources, either directly or indirectly.

An example might be if you create a `FileStream`, which will hold a file handle internally. The `FileStream` is a managed resource and the file handle is an unmanaged resource. In that situation, your `Dispose` method would dispose the `FileStream`, i.e. clean up the managed resource, and it will clean up its own unmanaged resource.