# What is the difference between finalize and dispose in .net?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, dispose, finalize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finalize vs Dispose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732864/finalize-vs-dispose)

Hi,

Recently I was quizzed in an interview about finalize and dispose. When is each one of them used and how is Garbage Collector related to them. Kindly share links to enlighten more on the topic.

Kindly share ...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't get the job offer then?  It is covered in any book about C# or the CLR.

Comment: I answered the question but what puzzled me when the interviewer asked what happens when we explicitly implement Dispose, what is the role of GC and where does the Finalize stands ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finalizers are run by the Garbage Collection before an object that is [eligible for collection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/10/10048149.aspx) is reclaimed. `Dispose()` is meant for cleaning up unmanaged resources, like network connections, files, handles to OS stuff, &c. It works best in conjunction with the `using` block where the compiler makes sure that `Dispose()` will be called immediately once you are done with an object – and also ensures that you cannot work with the object anymore once it's disposed.

Note that [finalizers don't *have to* run](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/09/10047586.aspx), so relying on that can be dangerous:

> **What this means for you:** Your programs cannot rely on finalizers keeping things tidy. Finalizers are a safety net, not a primary means for resource reclamation. When you are finished with a resource, you need to release it by calling `Close` or `Disconnect` or whatever cleanup method is available on the object. (The `IDisposable` interface codifies this convention.)

Careful also with the precise time when an object becomes eligible for collection. Read the article linked above – it's neither scope (a weird word which has noting to do with the lifetime of an object – it's [*“the region of program text in which it is legal to refer to [a named entity] by its unqualified name.”*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/03/what-s-the-difference-part-two-scope-vs-declaration-space-vs-lifetime.aspx)) nor is it strictly reference counting as an object can become eligible for collection even before the last reference to it goes away.

Comment: I would like to add that Finalizers should be used with care.  When you add a finalizer to your objects you are causing the runtime to hold onto the object for at least two GC cycles.  Also, inside the finalizer you are not guaranteed that any members of your object have not be reclaimed.  So accessing them may result in runtime exceptions.

Answer (score 17):

1. Finalize: <strike>undeterministic</strike> nondeterministic [destructor/finalizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx) called automatically by the Garbage Collector when there are no more references to this instance.
2. Dispose: deterministically called by the developer on an object implementing [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) to free resources.

Comment: I think "nondeterministic" is the right word here.

Comment: @Steven, my English is very poor. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: So if the developer implements IDisposable then would Finalize still be called by the GC ?

Comment: Yes it will when the object falls out of scope and when the CLR decides that it is a good time to perform a GC.

Comment: No, your English was completely understandable. I was just being picky about exactly the right word.

Comment: @Steven, no you are not picky, you are precise, it is important to use right words, programming is a precise science.

Comment: Note that the GC doesn't call the finalizer when there are no more references to the object, but when it actually has tried to dispose the object the first time.

Comment: "So if the developer implements IDisposable then would Finalize still be called by the GC " - if the developer implements the usual IDisposable pattern (see MSDN), then the Dispose method will call GC.SuppressFinalize, which will prevent the system from calling the Finalizer.