# Deserialize JSON data with C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am a new user in C# and I'm haveing some problems with my code.
I cant deserialize JSON data and I cant understand why:

```
            webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://" + Ip.ToString() + ":" + Port.ToString() + "........"); // Create a request to get server info
            webRequest.Method = "GET";
            webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webRequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar; //set container for HttpWebRequest 

            webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse(); // Get the response.

            reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()); 
            ServerInfo outObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServerInfo>(reader.ToString());
            my_label_ServerInfo.Text = outObject.message;
```

the server info class:

```
    public class ServerInfo
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string message_timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: For performance, you really shouldn't convert the `Stream` into a `string`. Try this instead. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the json that comes in your response body?

You might want to start off with a little test to make sure that the response body can correctly deserialize into your ServerInfo class. This is a matter of personal preference, but I like to do things a bit more explicitly as it helps to minimize unexpected behavior down the road.

For example, you could decorate your ServerInfo class like this:

```
// I chose MemberSerialization.OptIn so that all members need to be
// included explicitly, rather than implicitly (which is the default)
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class ServerInfo
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string message_timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you read the full HttpWebResponse body into a string like this:

```
reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
string responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
```

And lastly, you deserialize the response body into your ServerInfo class like this:

```
ServerInfo serverInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServerInfo>(responseBody);
```

This is assuming your json will come in the following format (or of a similar structure):

```
{
    "message": "Test Message",
    "message_timestamp": "2015-04-04T20:00:00"
}
```

Of course you should first check if your actual input deserializes correctly. I tried the format above in a unit test with this simple snippet:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("{");
sb.AppendLine();

sb.AppendFormat("\"{0}\": \"{1}\"", "message", "Test Message");
sb.Append(",");
sb.AppendLine();

sb.AppendFormat("\"{0}\": \"{1}\"", "message_timestamp", "2015-04-04T20:00:00");
sb.AppendLine();

sb.Append("}");

string json = sb.ToString();

ServerInfo serverInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServerInfo>(json);
```

**EDIT:** I completely agree with Aron in that you shouldn't unnecessarily use member fields and always make sure to dispose streams properly.

Improving my original answer with his suggestions, the following code I suggested earlier:

```
webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://" + Ip.ToString() + ":" + Port.ToString() + "........");
webRequest.Method = "GET";
webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webRequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()); 
string responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
ServerInfo serverInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServerInfo>
my_label_ServerInfo.Text = serverInfo.message;
```

Would change into this, which will perform better and is less prone to errors (I removed the comments for brevity, see Aron's answer for the explanations):

```
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://" + Ip.ToString() + ":" + Port.ToString() + "........");
webRequest.Method = "GET";
webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webRequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

using (var stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    ServerInfo serverInfo = (ServerInfo)serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(ServerInfo));
    my_label_ServerInfo.Text = serverInfo.message;
}
```

This will still work with the explicit JSON serialization attributes I added to your ServerInfo class. Note that they are not strictly necessary if the property names match up. I do this mainly just to show you how to gain more control over the serialization behavior without the need to implement a custom JsonSerializer.

Answer (score 3):

In C#,

```
reader.ToString()
```

will by default return the name of the class. In this case, "System.IO.StreamReader"

What you want is

```
reader.ReadToEnd()
```

which will return the entire contents of the stream as a string.

That should cause it to work, but be aware that it's not best practice. A few areas for consideration as you learn more about C#:

- As Aron mentioned, you should wrap all your streams and readers in ["using" statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to take advantage of the [Dispose pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable) which will let the runtime know it can release resources right away rather than [waiting for the finalizer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/732864/1869)
- As Fred demonstrated in his code, you can avoid converting the stream to a string and just let the Json.Net library do that.
- To ensure that you properly escape and format the request URL, you could use the [UriBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder) class: `new UriBuilder("http", ip, port, path).Uri)`
- You could use the newer and [async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) friendly [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient) class to download the data.

Answer (score 2):

Although Jeff is correct in WHY it doesn't work correctly. His answer still isn't the correct way to "fix" your code. Strings are very inefficient in C# (like almost EVERY programming language, and we avoid them as much as possible).

So you should be doing this instead.

```
        //STOP USING member fields (when possible), 
        //you encourage threading problems with member fields.
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://" + Ip.ToString() + ":" + Port.ToString() + "........"); // Create a request to get server info
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar; //set container for HttpWebRequest 

        var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse(); 

        //ALWAYS dispose your disposable correctly
        //Not disposing HttpStreams will cause you to leak TCP/IP
        //ports.
        using(var stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
        using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            ServerInfo outObject = (ServerInfo)serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(ServerInfo));
            my_label_ServerInfo.Text = outObject.message;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the approach of accessing JSON values with structured JSON types (object and array), without having to predefine types (such as the ServerInfo type) to deserialize into.

JsonObject serverinfo = (JsonObject)JsonObject.Load(responseStream);