# C++/Cli Destructors are not called

Tags: constructor, c++-cli, destructor

I am trying to investigate a memory leak problem and I found out that destructors in my library are not even called and I have the following code:

```
PPCamNET::Native::PpQueue::PpQueue(int capacity) : m_capacity(capacity), m_array(nullptr), m_head(0), m_tail(0)
{
    // Quick fix for case when capacity is 1 (single snap) 
    // and Push function crashes on 1st frame
    if (m_capacity == 1)
        m_capacity = 2;
    m_array = new FrameData[m_capacity];
    m_pushes = 0;
    m_pops = 0;
}
```

The above constructor's destructor should be called after PpQueue is destroyed, but it is not stopping at the break point.

```
PPCamNET::Native::PpQueue::~PpQueue()
{
    delete[] m_array; //<==== here I set a break point
}
```

PPQueue instance is created by AcqCache constructor.

```
PPCamNET::Internal::AcqCache::AcqCache(AcqBuffer^ acqBuffer)
{
    //m_stopWatchPush = Stopwatch::StartNew();
    //m_stopWatchPop = Stopwatch::StartNew();


    m_acqBuffer = acqBuffer;
    m_cacheLock = gcnew Object();
    m_processFrameRunning = true;
    try
    {
        m_frameDataCache = new PpQueue(acqBuffer->BufferSize / 2 + 1);
```

AcqCache destructor removes m_frameDataCache, which is PpQueue.

```
PPCamNET::Internal::AcqCache::~AcqCache()
{
    m_processFrameRunning = false;
    delete m_frameDataCache; // <== here another break point but not called
    delete[] m_frameInfoBuffer;
}
```

Finally the constructor of Acqusition creates an instance of m_acqCache with gcnew.

```
PPCamNET::Internal::Acquisition::Acquisition(AcqBuffer^ acqBuffer, 
        CameraSettings^ camSettings)
{
    m_eofEvent = gcnew AutoResetEvent(false);
    m_acqCache = gcnew AcqCache(acqBuffer);
```

I am puzzled why these destructors aren't called. Is this because GC didn't kick in to clear up m_acqCache causing other desructors not being called ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

GC will not call a destructor.  The C++/CLI compiler translates destructors into `IDisposable::Dispose()` implementation, and has a different syntax (`ClassName::!ClassName`) which gets translated to `Finalize`.

C# wrongly confuses this issue by using the name "destructor" for the CLR `Finalize` function.  Finalizers are not deterministic.  The `Dispose()` function is not called automatically by GC.  Not difficult once you know what's going on, but the terminology sure leads to confusion.

Comment: So in C++/CLI we don't use ClassName::~ClassName , but have to use lassName::!ClassName ? When do we use ClassName::~ClassName ?

Comment: @user1296153: That's been asked and answered here (now I've given you the rosetta stone so you can translate between C++/CLI verbiage and .NET runtime verbiage): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732864/finalize-vs-dispose